# ¿Hay algún conflicto entre los eventos click de la edición en línea la tabla de MudBlazor y el evento click de MudCheckBox?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Estoy intentando realizar una tabla de permisos que permita editar el MudCheckBox al darle click a cualquier parte de la fila y esto me funciona en cualquier parte de la fila, sin embargo no esta entrando en modo edición al darle click al MudCheckBox directamente, anexo mi código :

@if (applyButtonPosition.DisplayApplyButtonAtStart() || (editButtonPosition.DisplayEditButtonAtStart() && editTrigger == TableEditTrigger.EditButton))
{

}

```
     @if (applyButtonPosition.DisplayApplyButtonAtEnd() || (editButtonPosition.DisplayEditButtonAtEnd() && editTrigger == TableEditTrigger.EditButton))
     {
         <col style="width:50px;" />
     }
 </ColGroup>
 <HeaderContent>
     <MudTh>Opciones</MudTh>
     <MudTh>Permiso</MudTh>
     <MudTh></MudTh>
 </HeaderContent>
 <RowTemplate>
     <MudTd DataLabel="Opciones">@context.Actividad</MudTd>
     <MudTd><MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@context.Activo" Dense="false" Color="Color.Primary" /></MudTd>
 </RowTemplate>
 <RowEditingTemplate>
     <MudTd DataLabel="Opciones">@context.Actividad</MudTd>
     <MudTd DataLabel="Permiso">
         <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@context.Activo" Dense="false" Color="Color.Primary"></MudCheckBox>
     </MudTd>
 </RowEditingTemplate>
 <PagerContent>
     <MudTablePager />
 </PagerContent>
 <EditButtonContent Context="button">
     <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit" Class="pa-0" OnClick="@button.ButtonAction" Disabled="@button.ButtonDisabled" />
 </EditButtonContent>
```

se que @bind-Value me permite realizar la edición si fuera un MudTextField pero MudCheckedBox no tiene esta propiedad, gracias por la ayuda prestada.

He intentado varias cosas incluso tengo el código de una manera muy diferente ahora, ya que realizo la edición en línea a través de un botón en cada registro que me activa la edición en línea y me activa las opciones de guardar y cancelar, pero no es lo que quiero ya que quiero que sea de forma mas natural por eso intento usar la edición en línea que viene con la MudTable